# Android graphic size for all screen sizes

Tags: android, image, graphics

so I have create a background image using Adobe Photoshop CS6 of size 1024 pixels height by 512 pixels width with 320ppi resolution. I chose that size because I just thought it was good. I've been reading the android instructions about supporting multiple screen sizes, but I'm still confused on trying to figure out my next step once I created an image for my app.

I want to support all screen sizes and I understand that I need to resize my background image to support ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xdpi. How do I figure out what the pixel values I need to use resize my image to support ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xdpi? Also, once the background image has been resized, what naming convention do I have to give to each image file to place it in each ldpi-xdpi folder and make sure that the application automatically chooses the right image to support that screen size and density at launch?
I'm not new to java programming, but I am new when it comes to adding images and using them in an android app. SO please provide step by step guide if possible on what needs to be done when an image has been designed and how to implement it into your android app.

Thanks
David

Comment: You should give same for image of different resolution

Comment: You may find the Asset Studio Tool at http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-launcher.html to be helpful. It will generate the required files from your original art.  You will need to copy the ldpi/mdpi/... files into the corresponding res/drawable-lpdi, res/drawable-mpdi, etc. folders in your Eclipse project.  A given image will have the same file name (e.g. logo.png) in each drawable folder, but have a different resolution.

Comment: @DavidNA how your this problem solved? I have same problem.

Comment: Hey John, what I did in the end was to just keep all of my images in the assets folder and used the methods provided by android developer website to load an image based on the height and width specified for the image http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html.
This allows me to have high resolution images that can be used in just about any device instead of resizing the image and lowering its quality.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple tool : [Resolute-it](http://www.filedropper.com/resolute-it) , I developed for my office to handle this problem. The usage is pretty straightforward,let me know if you faced difficulties. The software needs JDK 1.5 or later.
This will automatically generate proper resolutions from your original artwork and place them to proper `res` folders;will create if not present(i.e. suppose, `drawable-hdpi` is absent,will get autogenerated).
Edit: The previous link is for Mac OSX only, you can get both the Mac version and original .jar/java version [here](http://www.filedropper.com/resolute-it_1)(which can be run on Windows & Linux too by double clicking it)

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. Now, I'd like to clear one more thing in my head. When is it appropriate to create an image of pixel size 100x100 or 48x60? I've made some icons that are 1024x1024 and then in my app I resize them to fit a size of maybe 80x80dp. Is that appropriate or if I know that an image in my app will be displayed at a smaller size then create the image at a smaller pixel size, say 200x200 pixels?

Comment: Did this software worked for you? Then you should mark this as answer.

Comment: I can't seem to download it at the moment because of the firewall my computer is behind. So I will have to wait till I get home shortly. As soon as I get home I will try it and post back my results :)

Comment: How do programs like the Asset Studio Tool and Resolute-it calculate the size of the image when resizing it? What is the formula used to calculate the size of the image for the corresponding density?

Comment: This Android doc is probably the best reference for you.  It will explain the various screen resolution issues and how to convert between dp and pixel units: http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html   If you want to reduce the size of your app, it would be better to use smaller images that are calculated from DP units.  Also, you may be able to get higher image quality by using a real imaging tool like Photoshop or Illustrator.

Answer (score 0):

(ran out space in my comment, so added here)
You may find the [Asset Studio Tool](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-launcher.html) to be helpful. It will generate the required files from your original art. You will need to copy the ldpi/mdpi/... files into the corresponding res/drawable-lpdi, res/drawable-mdpi, etc. folders in your Eclipse project. A given image will have the same file name (e.g. logo.png) in each drawable folder, but have a different resolution.

Android will automatically choose the appropriate ldpi/mdpi/... image when your app is launched, based on the screen characteristics of the device.

Comment: So this seems to work well for icons or small images, but for a background it doesn't seem to work for me. My background is not just made up of one or two colors. It is more of a carbon fiber pattern background. Thanks for the help though as this is a tool that still provides the help I need but for images of smaller size.

Comment: For background and all other image resources use the tool I mentioned before.